# on duplicate key update help

Tags: mysql, insert

I've tried to use the following but I get an error near 'WHERE'. Is this possible or do I need to use something else?

If the vendor does not exist, insert a new row. If the vendor does exist then update the row where the item_id is equal to something.

```
INSERT INTO vendor_item VALUES(1,1)
ON duplicate KEY UPDATE vendor_id=1
WHERE item_id=3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [INSERT statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) has no WHERE clause. You can only update the row that is the duplicate of what you wanted to insert so it makes no sense to have a condition.

If you want more complex actions MySQL has [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) available. But maybe it would be better to not do it entirely in MySQL.

Comment: Hi there. Yes, you're right, the INSERT statement doesn't have a WHERE clause. I thought that the WHERE clause was working off of the UPDATE statement. Seeing what I need, is there anything that you are aware of that I can use in this case?

Comment: @Jim [Triggers.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) But maybe it would be better to not do it entirely in MySQL. Are you restricted to it?

Comment: OK, thanks. I'm not sure that will work for me though. I'm attempting to give the user a way to update a record and if a row wasn't entered during the INSERT then it needs to be inserted during the update. I'm using FK constraints which makes it a bit more difficult.

Comment: Alin, I'm pretty much locked into MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

The way ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE works is as follows.  Say you have a table ("tableA") w/3 fields in it (fieldA, fieldB, fieldC) and let's pretend that fieldA is set to be unique.  Let's also pretend that there is already 1 row of data in that table:
fieldA   fieldB   fieldC
  1       'foo'   'test'

Considering the following query:

```
INSERT into tableA (fieldA,fieldB,fieldC) VALUES (1,'bar','example') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE fieldB=VALUES(fieldB),fieldC=VALUES(fieldC)
```

MySQL will assume that fieldA is unique and the new records will become:
fieldA   fieldB   fieldC
  1       'bar'  'example'

As w/anything else, I'd recommend reading up on it before using it in production:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Hmm, yeah not entirely sure what I was thinking when I wrote that.  Weird.